# Pain By Numbers - a friendly enigmatic puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus, nonogram, metapuzzles

I found this worksheet going though some old notes. Unfortunately, it seems the answer key got lost. Can anyone help?

[image: Scan of "PA1N 8Y NUM83R5" Worksheet]

Comment: rot13(qbrf gur svefg chmmyr jenc nebhaq gb gur bgure fvqr?)

Comment: @Alex bries rot13(ab, ohg jbeqf pna or hcfvqr qbja)

Comment: Is the final answer the paint by numbers, or figuring out the meaning of the 3 shapes?

Comment: @hb20007 The final answer is a satisfying answer to the "Why solve puzzles?' question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was quite a workout. Shouts-out to @Stiv and @DanielMathias for their contributions in the comment section.

1. Word search:

> 10 words in the grid: (ordered by location of first letter)
>  Stain, Sneak, Elves, Term, Pint, Plan, Pits, Guts, Maul, Mass
>  [image]
>  The unused letters spell out **CINNABAR**

2. (Unknown)

> Guessing at the rules, there's an orthogonal path between the arrows spelling out "You found the color **BONE**"

3. Rebus:

> "bulb" minus "bees" = *ul*
>  "two ramen" minus "women" = *tra*
>  soldier guy with no uneaten crayons in sight = *marine*
>  Combining everything: **ULTRAMARINE**

4. Nonogram (pictocross puzzler):

> [image]
>  The unshaded parts seem to spell out "No 1", possibly <s>NUMBERONE</s>. In the comments, @Stiv managed to read between the shaded areas, and found "So it is proclaimed the color is **TURQUOISE**, a hue of blue you surely knew"
>
>  (Sorry about the lack of progress pictures, I decided to add an intermediate step whenever I had to pause and work out some non-trivial nonogram logic. Turns out it wasn't necessary.)

5. Alphametics

This one's super tricky, since the solution to the alphametic is non-unique. But after a long while staring at the weird pattern of the puzzle, it turns out is doesn't matter! Let's solve the regular puzzle first:

> From the last digit, **D = 1 or 6**
>  From the third digit, since W cannot equal D, **W = D-1** and there *must* be a carry
>  From the second digit, since P cannot equal D, **P = D+1** and there *must not* be a carry, so D+W<10, and therefore
>  **D = 1, W = 0, P = 2**
>  **A = 3, U = 5 or vice versa**
>  **E = 9, R = 7 or vice versa**

giving these plausible additions:

> 31191 + 52071 = 83262
>  31171 + 52091 = 83262
>  51191 + 32071 = 83262
>  51171 + 32091 = 83262

But now we do what the alphametic words say, and

> "Add upwards", meaning we turn the grid upside down, and do the addition that way around. This changes the direction the carried ones go, and also gives a meaning for the superfluous addition symbols in the picture. Apart from the letter assignment, it doesn't matter which equation we pick, (the sum must remain equal), so we get 17025+19113 = 36138. Assigning the letters back to the numbers while sticking to the substitution scheme above leaves only one possible (albeit topically quite painful) colour:
>
> ```
>       KUDZU =        83163 =               26238 =
>       -----          -----     rotate      -----     -
>       ADDED +        51191 +    180        17023 +    |  These rows
>     + UPWRD   ->   + 32071      deg      + 19115       > are always the
>       -----          -----                 -----      |  valid addition.
>     = 83262        = 83262               = 36138     -
> ```

BUT WAIT! (This is an interruption from the future. You can also call it an edit, if you don't like time travel.)

> The final step (far below) suggests the answer is not KUDZU, but **BEIGE** instead.

But where on Earth are we going to find such a word? Surely we cannot suddenly just reassign some numbers? Luckily, we won't have to. Remember the addition result above?

> [image]
>  (Also independently found and kindly shared in the comments by @DanielMathias)

6. Connect-y dots:

> [image]

Doesn't look all that delicious to me.. Judging from the extra clues at the bottom middle of the page, we should find something with 9 letters. So maybe

> <s>RASPBERRY</s>? (Looks more like an **ARTICHOKE** -@Stiv)

7. Pentominoes

> Fitting everything in, the grid spells out
>  "Congrats on finding **VIOLET** (the color, not the flower)"
>  [image]

### Putting it all together

Filling these in at the bottom, and checking the marked letters, we find the answer to the question at the top:

Why solve puzzles?

> For the **BLUE BRIGHT COOL** of it.

**EDIT:** ..which, it turns out, isn't some obscure idiom after all. So.. maybe it's a wordplay riddle of some kind? Going through bright, cool shades of blue, the best I got is

> "For the **[PROCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLnG4.png)** of it".

And yeah, my answer from puzzle 5 doesn't fit this. The intended solution to puzzle 5 is most likely

> **BEIGE**.

This solution has now been sent backwards in time and retconned into the answer of step 5.

And here's the final pain-by-numbers, fully living up to its name:

> [image]

**BUT WAIT! There's more!**

@cap noticed something very interesting:

> Each question (and the title) has a number in it with a dotted square surrounding it, either in the question itself, or in the solution:
>   [image]

Starting with the title, and ending with the pain-by-numbers (which might actually give an 8, if we colour by the hidden numbers scheme as the picture seems to suggest), we get the number sequence

1-7-3-2-1-6-1-5-3

Interpreting this gives you

> ..the honour of finding the "true ending" to this puzzle. I didn't manage. The only unfilled part on the page is the "My name" line, so it stands to reason that the author has hidden their name in this somehow. The best I could do was "Esi Gizeli", which doesn't ring a bell even with a google search.

---

**EDIT:** After finally catching an entire hour of shuteye, I think I got it. It's about the boxed numbers, but there's no remapping or hidden messages. Instead,

> the **entire page** is the *real* pain-by-numbers. Like so:
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: rot13(Er 4, ernq gur terraf sbe n cnffntr gung erirnyf GHEDHBVFR; 6 ybbxf yvxr na NEGVPUBXR gb zr...)

Comment: Ah, brilliant! But does this mean I don't get to go to bed yet?

Comment: [image spoiler for #5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzyYo.png), though I guess I should have used at least one lowercase letter there...

Comment: @DanielMathias thanks, got there on my own, too a good while to mage the image though.

Comment: All I see is a black box for your image. Unless I click on it, then I see the animation.

Comment: Thanks again, @DanielMathias. Imgur's automatic rescaling doesn't seem to like my gif.

Comment: Nice job. One thing i noticed rot13(Rnpu bs gur zvavchmmyrf nyfb lvryqf n ahzore va n qnfurq fdhner. bar:frira, gjb:guerr, guerr:gjb, sbhe:bar, svir:fvk, fvk:bar, frira:svir. Ba gur svany cnvag ol ahzoref gur ahzoref ner va qnfurq fdhnerf fb znlor gur pbybef arrq gb or erznccrq.)

Comment: That's a great observation, @cap! but how would you do the remapping, with 4 and 6 both yielding the same number? (It may be obvious, but my bedtime came and went several hours ago already.) Just ignoring that problem changes the final image so that the saturated colours make an 8 instead of a 3 as it's now.

Comment: Haha good point @Bass. Something to sleep on!

Comment: rot13(Vs fbzrubj 1=R, 2=G, 3=F, 5=TT, 6=E naq 7=N gur svany ahzrevp frdhrapr lbh unir sbhaq pbhyq or na ncg fhofgvghgvba pvcure sbe R-N-F-G-R-E-R-TT-F!) For the record, I don't think this is the intention but it was such a lovely fit I had to share :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the final word can be found by rot13(ybbxvat ng gur ragver cntr nf vs vg jrer n avar frtzrag YRQ qvtvg qvfcynl,  jvgu gur ahzoref va qnfurq obkrf orvat gur ynoryf sbe rnpu frtzrag.  Oevtug, oyhr naq pbby jbhyq rnpu pyhr juvpu frtzragf gb ghea ba.)  I can't figure it out though.

Comment: Such a good answer! I particularly like the description of the Rebus :)
All that's left is one dashed box that hasn't been used, and the ultimate answer to why we do puzzles.

Comment: bar obk be n ohapu bs fznyy obkrf?

Comment: Can't see any unused dashed boxes, and can't come up with a better "ultimate answer" than what's already there. Others in this comment section: plz halp! :-)

Comment: @Bass You haven't used the bigger dashed box in puzzle 6. The bound region in the bottom of the artichoke looks like a 4 to me.

Comment: Hint: rot13 (Ora W naq hfre39583 ner irel zhpu ba gur evtug cngu.)

Comment: We are 15+ comments deep, no need to spare anyone here from spoilers. So the next steps are 1) re-colour box 6 in turquoise 2) select all boxes which are "blue" by some definition, interpret as a letter. 3) repeat for "bright" and "cool" 4: combine the three letters to spell a word that doesn't describe this part of the process. (because properties of colours are highly subjective, extremely culturally dependent, and physiologically inaccessible to many.) Did I get it?

Comment: @Bass That's the solution, yea. I did try fairly hard to pick a set of colors and descriptors that were as un-subjective as possible

Comment: @Bass, is there a way for me to edit your answer to add the final step?

Comment: I think you can just click "edit". Since you don't have the edit privilege yet, your edit would then go in the approval queue. But I'll try to get around to it myself when I find the time.